# add sounds, buttons and image on the function of button programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i want to know i add sound & image or label on the function of button which is created prgrammatically on the click of button. firstly my sound was working fy9, but after adding image and label on that same function , sound is not working.

help ME!

Anks.....

Answer (score 0):

try this, worked for me:

in the .h file of the view controller ur using add the "-(IBAction) playSound:(id)sender;" before "@end"

in the .m file of the view controller add the following code:

-(IBAction) playSound:(id)sender{

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"awh_man" ofType:@"wav"];
AVAudioPlayer* sound =[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];

sound.delegate=self;
[sound play];

}
```

NOTE that you need to add the AVFoundation framework to your project.
Good luck.